# Why is Germany not in the New Hanseatic League?

Tags: european-union, germany

The Bad Weather Coalition, more formally known as the [New Hanseatic League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Hanseatic_League), is a group of EU member states Ireland, Netherlands, Denmark, Sweden, Finland, Estonia, Latvia, Lithuania, which are all “fiscally conservative northern European states”.  The original [Hanseatic league](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanseatic_League) very much included cities like Hamburg, Bremen, Rostock, Stettin (now Szczecin) and Danzig (now Gdańsk).  Based on the name and the political aims, I would expect Germany to be part of the club.  Why isn't it?  Was Germany not invited (perhaps the founders wanted to remain a club of smaller nations), or does Germany not want to be in the Bad Weather Coalition?

Comment: Why use a derogative name when the formal name is better known? Google doesn't even mention the correct page on the first page when looking for "Bad Weather Coalition".

Comment: @Sjoerd I don't know if it's derogatory, I find it funny :)

Comment: I don't know why it's called the New Hanseatic League, but presumably the analogy is that it's an alliance of small states to counteract the powerful centrist forces of larger and more powerful neighbours. Inviting Germany to join would then make about as much sense as inviting Prussia to join the original Hanseatic League: that is to say, it would defeat the entire purpose.

Comment: I'm surprised anybody would call high tax, large public sector countries "fiscally conservative".

Comment: Perhaps a better question is: Why not Poland?

Comment: @dan04 They all seem to be wealthier-than-average member states.

Comment: @janh: fiscally conservative is only about keeping a low level of national debt AFAIK

Comment: @hkBst It certainly has a broader meaning than that (low ratio of govt budget vs gpd, low taxes etc), but even with that meaning, it's hard to unify Ireland (70% of gdp) and Estonia (8%) as both being "fiscally conservative" ;)

Comment: @janh Within the EU, the target level for national debt is 60% of GDP. Only a few stay below that in all years (Ireland was hit hard, so 70% isn't halve bad, and they are reducing it now). Gross simplification: Most northern EU countries try to stay on the good side in good years, while the southern EU countries don't care about it at all. As a result, the debt-loaded countries try to get other countries to pay for their debts (e.g. by trying to issue EU-guaranteed bonds), while the fiscally conservative countries don't want to sign a blank cheque.

Comment: @Sjoerd I do understand, I just find the label "fiscally conservative" problematic, because it traditionally has a much broader meaning that most of these countries' policies aren't aligned with. I'd similarly not call a country "environmentalist" just because it has regulations regarding polution. To each his own I suppose. This isn't the OP's fault, either - Wikipedia introduced the term.

Comment: @Sjoerd Southern european countries don't care, or just *can't*? To reduce your national debt you must run budget surpluses for quite a long time, or your economy must grow greatly so your debt/wealth ratio shrinks in percentage - not in value. You seem to think that those countries have excellent GDP's because of that sensible economic policy. It's the other way round. If Sweden had the GDP of Greece, it would run on greek policies, no matter how they would like to keep their debt controlled.

Comment: An analysis of the economic and political differences between northern and southern Europe are far too complicated to be resolved in a set of comments.

Comment: @Rekesoft Sjoerd “analysis” is simply the usual self-serving nonsense. Greece has suffered massively for the sake of preserving Northern Europe from taking any responsibility for its toxic policies, Spain was in fact a fiscally conservative country widely held as a role model before *private* debt financed by European banks put it in huge trouble. Meanwhile, far from signing a check (blank or otherwise), Germany profited massively from the structure of the Eurozone and merely paid to save its own banks.

Comment: @Relaxed I don't disagree, my point was just that this set of comments is not the right place to get into any detail on this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Many decision in the EU are pre-arranged by the German-French axis, which in practice means that the smaller countries don't have much influence.

The New Hanseatic League aims to give the smaller countries with similar views more influence. Therefore, it is a counter-balance against the German-French axis.

It would be strange if Germany were on both sides.

An advantage for Germany for not being in this group, is that they can be the negotiator-in-the-middle, while the New Hanseatic League is free to voice concerns shared by Germany.

I think that both the New Hanseatic League and Germany are happy with this arrangement, so there is no reason for them to join.

Comment: negotiator-in-the-middle of the New Hanseatic League and who?